# Angular data binding on back press

Tags: angular

I have an SPA which allows users to enter some parameters to search a digital collection of postcards. The search function is a call to the api, which queries the database and brings back a JSON which is finally displayed in a gallery format. Upon selecting one of the images, the app navigates to a new view, where details of the selected image are displayed. If I press the browser's back button, the behaviour is as expected, and the user is taken back to the gallery. Sadly, whilst the data is there (console.log outputs the content of the object holding the data), it is not shown on the page.

I thought it might be the way I'm doing the call, but since the data is there, I don't believe it's the case. Am I doing something wrong with the way I'm binding the data to the template? What am I missing? Any ideas or suggestions are much appreciated!

Thank you!

```
<div *ngIf="checked else details">
    <mat-card >
        <p>Some information of how you could search...</p>
    </mat-card>
</div>

<ng-template #details>
<!-- <p>Test</p> -->
<div>
    <div fxFlex="100" fxLayoutWrap fxLayoutAlign="start start">
        <mat-card *ngFor="let postcard of postcards" [routerLink]="['/postcard', postcard.postcard_id]">
            <img mat-card-image [src]="postcard?.img" [alt]="postcard?.postcard_id" class="postcards"> <!-- (click)="display_postcard(index)"> -->
            <mat-card-actions>
                <span class="span-left">{{postcard?.posted_from}}</span>
                <span class="span-right">{{postcard?.year}}</span>
            </mat-card-actions>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
private years: any;
private api: ApiService;
public ref: ChangeDetectorRef;

public postcards: Observable<Array <Postcard>>;
public static checked: boolean = true;

constructor(api: ApiService, public router: Router, ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.api = api;
    this.ref = ref;

    //filter for the proper event
    this.router.events.filter(e => e.constructor.name === 'RoutesRecognized').pairwise()
      .subscribe((e: any[]) => {
        if(e[1].urlAfterRedirects == '/search'){
          let arr = (e[0].urlAfterRedirects).split("/");
          if(arr[1] == 'postcard'){
            console.log(this.postcards); //outputs the correct return of the api call :)
            // console.log(this.ref._view.component.postcards);
            // this.ref.reattach();
          }
        }
    });
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.getYears();
}

private getYears(){
  this.api.getYears().subscribe(res => {
    this.years = res;
  });
}

search = function(){
  this.api.getPostcards(this.surname != null ? this.surname : '', this.town != null ? this.town : '', this.from != null ? this.from : '', this.year != null ? this.year.year : '').subscribe(res => {
    this.postcards = res;
    // console.log(this.postcards);
  })
}
```

and the api call:

```
public getPostcards(surname, town, from, year) : Observable<Postcard []> {
    return this.http.post(this.urlBase + '/getPostcardsBySearch', {
      'surname' : surname,
      'town' : town,
      'from' : from,
      'year' : year
    }).map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `postcards` is an Observable, therefore your template should behave with async datas. I suggest you to add a `$` to your observables names so that you wont be confused. `postcards$` for instance.

[The `pipe` async](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) will subscribe to your observable :

```
<div *ngIf="postcards$|async as postcards"> <!-- this will subscribe to postcards$ and bind it the name postcards-->

 <mat-card *ngFor="let postcard of postcards" [routerLink]="['/postcard', postcard.postcard_id]">
        <img mat-card-image [src]="postcard?.img" [alt]="postcard?.postcard_id" class="postcards"> <!-- (click)="display_postcard(index)"> -->
        <mat-card-actions>
            <span class="span-left">{{postcard?.posted_from}}</span>
            <span class="span-right">{{postcard?.year}}</span>
        </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

Comment: Fair point re $, however, this still doesn't show the gallery on the back press :/

Comment: what's your `network` tab of the devtools showing, is the request of your items being made ?

Comment: It's called on the first instantiation of the page. Once I go to the details page and come back to the gallery, there's no call done. There's no need to do so since the postcard array is still in memory and it's visible on the console.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! What I ended up doing was to save the repository to the localStorage and detect when the user is navigating away/to the page in order to remove/show the selection.

This is the new piece of code:

```
  constructor(api: ApiService, public router: Router, ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
this.api = api;
this.ref = ref;

//filter for the proper event
this.router.events.filter(e => e.constructor.name === 'RoutesRecognized').pairwise()
  .subscribe((e: any[]) => {
    //when navigating away from the search page -> delete the repository
    if(e[0].url == '/search'){
      let arr = (e[1].urlAfterRedirects).split("/");
      if(arr[1] != 'postcard'){
        localStorage.removeItem('postcards');
      }
    }

    //when navigating away from the details page of the postcard -> delete the repository
    let arr = (e[0].url).split("/");
    if(arr[1] == 'postcard' && e[1].urlAfterRedirects != '/search'){
      localStorage.removeItem('postcards');
    }
  });
```

}

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.postcards = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('postcards'));
}

search = function(){
  this.api.getPostcards(this.surname != null ? this.surname : '', this.town != null ? this.town : '', this.from != null ? this.from : '', this.year != null ? this.year.year : '').subscribe(res => {
    this.postcards = res;
    localStorage.setItem('postcards', JSON.stringify(this.postcards));
  })
}
```